# How to use Runnable.wait() in AsyncTask? Why does the AsyncTask NOT wait...?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

I am using AsyncTask to run a background operation. Of course switching to another thread while already working in a background thread does not make a lot of sense in general, except the other thread is the UI thread. This what I would like to to: While the task is running I need to "access" the UI, e.g. to show a dialog to ask the user how to proceed.

- run the background task
- stop the task at some point to get user feedback
- switch to the UI thread to show dialog and ask for input
- switch back to background task and continue work

How can this be done? I thought I could use `Runnable` with `myActivity.runOnUiThread(runnable)` but this does not work:

```
private void copyFiles() {
    CopyTask copyTask = new CopyTask(this);
    copyTask.execute();
}

// CustomAsyncTask is a AsyncTask subclass that takes a reference to the current
// activity as parameter
private class CopyTask extends CustomAsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private doCopy;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {              
        // Custom code, e.g. copy files from A to B and check for conflict
        for (File file : allFiles) {
            doCopy = true;

            if (isConflict(file)) {
                // Stop current thread and ask for user feedback on UI Thread

                Runnable uiRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Pos 1. --> Execute custom code, e.g. use AlertDialog to ask user if file should be replaced...
                        doCopy = false;

                        synchronized (this) {
                           this.notify();
                        }
                    }
                });  

                synchronized(uiRunnable) {
                    // Execute code on UI thread
                    activity.runOnUiThread(uiRunnable);

                    // Wait until runnable finished
                    try {
                        uiRunnable.wait();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e ) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Pos 2. --> Continue work
            if (doCopy)
               copyFromAToB(File);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Within `doInBackground()` (--> in a background thread) the `AsyncTask` calls `activity.runOnUiThread(uiRunnable)`. Next `uiRunnable.wait()` is called. Regarding to the [docu](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) `wait()` should do the following:

> Causes the calling thread to wait until another thread calls the
>   notify() or notifyAll() method of this object.

Thus the background thread should wait to continue its work until `this.notify()` (== `uiRunnable.notifiy()`) is called on another thread (= the UI thread), shouldn't it?

**Well, id does not wait!** After calling `uiRunnable.wait()` the background thread immediately continues by jumping to `if (doCopy)...`. It seems that the background thread and the main thread are executed in parallel (not surprising since this is what thread do...) and thus its a race condition whether `doCopy = false` on the UI thread or `if (doCopy)` on the background thread is reached first.

**How is this possible? Why doesn't `wait()` works as described?** Or am I getting something wrong?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**
To avoid missunderstandings: Of course I know the lifecycle methodes of AsyncTask but as far as I understand them, they are not what I am looking for (see my reply to the comment blow).

Interrupting the AsyncTask as soon as a UI interaction is necessary, query the UI and start a new AsyncTask would be possible of course. However this would result in code which is very hard to read/understand/maintain.

As I understand the docu of `wait()` everything should work fine here. Primary question is not how to do UI interaction during the lifecycle of an AsyncTask but why `wait()`does not work as expected.

Comment: Please read on the lifecycle methods of an Async Task!

Comment: Sure, I know these methods. But they only allow to do UI Changes **before** or **after** the task ran. `onProgressUpdate()`can be uses **during** the execution but regarding to the docu it is not guranteed when this method will run. The background thread will continue its work and not wait for `onProgressUpdate()` to return. But this is what I am looking for. Thus in this special case these methods does not help, do they?

Comment: Then essentially you need to divide your task into parts -- Process and then update the UI -- Process and then update the UI else you might want to consider a Handler thread.

Comment: Thanks. Please have a look at my EDIT. Splitting up the process in multiple AsyncTasks could solve the problem but I think it would not be a very nice solution. Additionally the primary question is why `wait()`does not work as expected and not how to circumvent the fact that it does not :)

Comment: Where is `activity` declared by the way? I just through together a near exact copy of your code and it works fine. Maybe it's not waiting because `isConflict(file)` is true, so the wait/notify runnable section is never running anyway.

Comment: Note that I am not using `AsyncTask` but `CustomAsyncTask`. This is a direct subclass of `AsyncTask` which takes an Activity as constructor argument to allow the later access. However this just demo code. Even if I call the Runnable directly without checking `isConflict(file)` before the `AsyncTask` does not wait()...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Basics

When you start an `AsyncTask` first the `onPreExecute()` method runs on the UI thread. You can  override this method to make changes to the UI prior to the `doInBackground()` method running.

After the `doInBackground()` method finishes, the `onPostExecute()` method runs on the UI thread, so you can use this to make changes to the UI from here. If you need to make regular changes to the UI Thread **during** the `doInBackground()` method you override the `onProgressUpdate()` method which runs on the UI Thread, and then call it from within `doInBackground()`, which will allow you to periodically update the UI.

You could use something like the following;

```
private class DoStuffTask extends AsyncTask {

   @Override
   protected void doInBackground(Object... args) {
       // Do stuff
       onProgressUpdate(x);
       // Do more stuff
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... args) {
       // Update your UI here
   }
}
```

Now if this doesn't quite do it and you want the AsyncTask to wait for **input** during the `doInBackground()` method it is probably worth considering using multiple `AsyncTasks` instead. You can then finish each `AsyncTask`, ask for input, and then start a new `AsyncTask` to continue working.

Given that `AlertDialog` instances are asynchronous, this is probably the preferred solution because you can start the next `AsyncTask` from the `AlertDialog` itself.

### Using wait() in an AsyncTask

If you would prefer to use a single `AsyncTask` you can use wait from within your `AsyncTask` to prevent execution continuing until some condition is met. Instead of using a new `Runnable` we are just using two threads in this instance, the thread running `doInBackground()` and the main thread, and we are synchronizing on the `AsycTask` itself.

Example below;

```
public class TestTask extends AsyncTask{

    private boolean notified;
    private Promptable p;
    public interface Promptable { public abstract void prompt(); }

    public TestTask(Promptable p){
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        Log.d("First", "First");
        onProgressUpdate(null);
        synchronized(this){
            while(!notified){
                try{
                    this.wait();
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){ }                    
            }
        }
        Log.d("Second", "Second");
        return null;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... args){       
        synchronized(this){
            notified = true;
            p.prompt();               
            this.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, assume that your `Activity` is parsed into the `AsyncTask`'s constructor, and that it implements an interface we create called `Promptable`. You'll notice that even though we're calling `wait()`  we are putting it in a while loop. If we didn't do this, and somehow `notify()` got called before `wait()` then your thread would lock up indefinitely. Also, you can't depend on the fact that your thread will wait forever, so the while loop ensures that it doesn't continue until notify is called.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, I know these methods. But they only allow to do UI Changes **before** or **after** the task ran. `onProgressUpdate()`can be uses **during** the execution but regarding to the docu it is not guranteed when this method will run. The background thread will continue its work and not wait for `onProgressUpdate()` to return. But this is what I am looking for. Thus in this special case these methods does not help, do they?

Comment: Good point. In which case I would just use multiple `AsyncTasks` to do your job. When your first task finishes, produce the prompt and then start the next to continue the job.

Comment: Thanks. Please have a look at my EDIT. Splitting up the process in multiple AsyncTasks could solve the problem but I think it would not be a very nice solution. Additionally the primary question is why `wait()`does not work as expected and not how to circumvent the fact that it does not :)

Comment: @AndreiHerford - Cool. I'll have a re-read and see if I can come up with anything, but manually handling threads to work with the UI in Android is notoriously a pain in the arse. You might be able to halt the `doInBackground()` thread by using a while loop which waits from the response asked for by the `onProgressUpdate()` before continuing .

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Constructing a wait using while loop could work I think. I will try that. However this would be a hack and not a real solution. Any idea what `wait()` does not work as expected? Is this a bug in `wait()`or in my expectations?

Comment: @AndreiHerford - I've updated my answer to include example of using `wait()` and using the while loop with with `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test this and let you know the result!

Comment: @AndreiHerford - Did you ever find a solution for your problem?

Comment: Hi, I was just about to write. I am using the `while(notDoneYet)` and it works perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: by calling Thread.sleep() aren't you blocking the entire thread running AsyncTasks ?  This may affect other AsyncTasks unless of course there are none.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald I believe you're right. I might find some time to see if I can clarify this answer. I may even remove the thread sleep recommendation entirely.

Comment: Let us know if you find a solution to this - seems like a bad idea to call Thread.sleep() any time a thread pool is being used.  Surely there must be a mechanism to get an asynch task to wait without blocking the entire queue.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald It's been a little while since I wrote these answer, or indeed any android, but doesn't the wait notify solution at the bottom perform the same function but without blocking the whole thread?